# FlickrKit Standard Account

Tags: ios, objective-c, flickr

I am wondering if there is a way to login automatically so that the username and password would be hardcoded into the app and it would be used as a way for the user to upload photos without them having to have a Flickr account?

Comment: This question is incredibly broad.  What kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: basically a general overview on how to authenticate the FlickrKit class with a standard user account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sound of your question, you want your app to have a Flickr account associated with it so that users won't have to have their own Flickr account. Then, you want your app to authenticate with this account, and allow users to upload to it. Storing login credentials "hard-coded" is a terrible idea - someone poking around with the app bundle may be able to find the login info -  which is why we have OAuth authentication schemes. By reviewing Flickrkit's github documentation, they have an API for authenticating your app. So what you would do is first generate the authorization token for the shared account using your app, then distribute the auth Token that's generated in NSUserDefaults in your application and use that as the auth Token for general distribution.

Answer (score 0):

So...
Your question is kinda broad so I'm not sure this is the answer your looking for but maybe it'll help.

If the user must login then somewhere the login information must be stored as a variable. All you need to do is save those variables containing the login info and when your app loads run your function to login with those saved variables.